# How to open a file in gedit with zenity --file-selection as root

Tags: command-line, root, scripts, gksu, zenity

I try to open a file in gedit with the file-selection option of zenity. It's very easy to do it for file that i can access in normal mode, but I wanna open too some configuration files (as for exemple the conf files for vpnc) which are in a '700' folder (only the user root can read, write and execute the folder) I dont wanna change the permissions for the folder.

I tryed this :

`gksudo -u root "gedit $(zenity --file-selection)"`

but it didn't work

Is someone have an idea of how I can do it ?

Thx in advance folks

BR,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the command you're running, the `$(...)` syntax is evaluated by your shell before calling `gksudo`.  What you want is for it to be evaluated by a shell running as root.  Perhaps try something like this:

```
gksudo -u root "sh -c 'gedit \$(zenity --file-selection)'"
```

Comment: Whoah, It's perfectly working...Thanks...

 OK I'll try to understand the command line. With `gksudo -u root` we subsitutte ourselve to the user root. I guess that with `sh -c` we invoke a new shell instance  as user root, where we open gedit. Because `gedit $(zenity --file-selection` is the command sent to the new shell, we need to escape char '$'. That's right ?

Thx a lot again James